# retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices and retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers return an empty array

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, bluetooth

I have two apps running one on OSX and one on iOS. A bluetooth connection is established between them using the CoreBluetooth framework, and support for background capabilities for the iOS app has been added. This is working perfectly fine, and communication with the iOS app in the background still works even after a while in the background. 
However, when the iOS device goes out of range, I have to use retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers to re-connect when the device is back in range since the app is in the Background and therefore I cannot scan for it as its UUID would not be advertised ([as mentioned in Core Bluetooth Background Processing for iOS Apps)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html). I tried using retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices with the iOS app in the foreground to figure what the problem is, but the function is always returning an empty array, although the connection is already established. For the former case, I am passing my custom service CBUUID object as specified in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBCentralManager/retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:):

```
let connectedPeripherals = centralManager!.retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices([CBUUID(string: "109F17E4-EF68-43FC-957D-502BB0EFCF46")])
```

Trying to get the peripheral to re-connect to the OSX app while it's in the background, using

```
let peripherals = centralManager!.retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers([NSUUID(UUIDString: "109F17E4-EF68-43FC-957D-502BB0EFCF46")!])
```

as per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBCentralManager/retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:) also yields an empty array. Also to mention that I tried this function with the iOS app in the foreground but also to no avail.

Any idea what could possibly be going wrong here?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Does your UUID identify a service or a device? It is likely that you are using it incorrectly in at least one of those calls.

Comment: I am having trouble with Method as well. I am able to Get the Device, It shows as connected. But when i ask to connect to that peripheral it never gets connected. No idea whats happening.